# Prevent sound when phone is in silent mode in javascript

Tags: javascript, ios, facebook-instant-games

I am working on simple HTML5 game which plays sound on click of a button. I got the below response from Facebook app review team.

**Developer Policy 1.9 - Build a Quality Product**
We found that your game does not mute sound when iOS silent mode is enabled. On iOS devices, games should be muted when silent mode is enabled.
Please resolve this issue before resubmitting for review.

I am not sure how to control sounds on iOS devices from javascript when phone is on silent mode. How to fix this issue. Please help.